# A way to add code & join together?

Tags: html, bash

Ok say I have 2 text docs, One containing the names of documents and the other containing the link to where that document is hosted.

Is there a way/program or bash code that will allow me to make it all come together so it would look like this

```
<li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_KBy1Yc657LdnR5MGFXWVZZcnc" target="_blank">Cocoa in a nutshell.chm</a></li>
```

So I guess add

```
<li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href=" to the beginning of each line in th links doc
```

then

```
target="_blank">
```

to the beginning of the title docs then of course add

```
</a></li>
```

to the end so that it will all come together.

Also the links and titles will already be matched up by what line number they are on in each doc.

Comment: Have you heard of [PHP](http://php.net)?

Comment: yes - what language? :-D

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - PHP would work but is targeted for Web applications.  BASH would make more sense as it was already mentioned, or any of the general purpose scripting languages.

Comment: did you mean "what language" for me? if so bash or c# lol . but i appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

just for  fun:

```
$ cat file1 file2
hello.doc
world.xls
plaintext-is-better.txt
extensionsareforsuckers
http://loldoc.com/phileurl
http://spreadsheetfactory.uk/mooooooooo
http://onlinetext.org/files/109874
http://extensionssuck.info/4u373

$ for i in {1..4}; do \
     sed -n $i'p' file1 | tr  '\n' '|';\
     sed -n $i'p' file2 ;done |\
     awk -F\| '{printf "<a href=%s>%s</a>\n", $2, $1 }'
<a href=http://loldoc.com/phileurl>hello.doc</a>
<a href=http://spreadsheetfactory.uk/mooooooooo>world.xls</a>
<a href=http://onlinetext.org/files/109874>plaintext-is-better.txt</a>
<a href=http://extensionssuck.info/4u373>extensionsareforsuckers</a>
```